# homotopy groups of an orbifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

The isometry group of the 3-dimensional hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^{3}$ is $PSL(2,\mathbf{C})$. What are the homotopy groups of the quotient space $\mathbb{H}^{3}/PSL(2,\mathbf{Z})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As a topological space, this is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{D}^3,$ so the homotopy groups are whatever they are for $\mathbb{D}^3.$ As an orbifold, the fundamental group is $\mathbb{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Z}),$ while the higher homotopy groups vanish, since the universal cover is $\mathbb{H}^3.$

**NOTE** Thanks to HJRW for the correction.

Comment: $S^2$? Don't you mean the 3-ball?

Comment: @HJRW Actually, unless I am confused (possible, due to lack of sleep), the quotient of $\mathbb{H}^2$ by $SL(2, Z)$ is a sphere (topologically), and I think the quotient of $\mathbb{H}^3$ is topologically just that cross a line. No?

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that the topological quotient is not $\mathbb{S}^2$, but rather $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it's the $j$-line...)

Comment: @IgorRivin, the quotient of $\mathbb{H}^2$ by $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is the modular orbifold, which is a *punctured* 2-sphere with order-2 and -3 cone points.  (This follows from the usual picture of the fundamental domain for the action on $\mathbb{H}^2$.)

Comment: @IgorRivin, perhaps it's helpful to remember, which I know you do well, that $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is virtually *free*. This couldn't be the case if its action on the hyperbolic plane were cocompact.

Comment: @HJRW I generally count the orbifold points as part of the space, is this what the disagreement is about?

Comment: @HJRW Oh, I see, the disagreement is about the cusp. You are absolutely right. Told you I was underslept :(

Comment: @IgorRivin Can you elaborate more, please ? How do you obtain that the quotient is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{D}^{3}$. BTW is $\mathbb{D}^{3}=\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbf{R}^{4}| x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+t^{2}\leq 1 \}$ ?

Comment: The action on $\mathbb{H}^2$ gives the modular orbifold as quotient. The modular orbifold is a doubled triangle, with one vertex at infinity, so topologically a punctured sphere, so a disk. The action on $\mathbb{H}^3$ is that cross $\mathbb{R}.$